# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: TypeError Message: Unsupported operand types: string + int

Tags: php, web

```
Type: TypeError

Message: Unsupported operand types: string + int

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\perpustakaan\application\models\Anggota_model.php

Line Number: 46

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\perpustakaan\application\models\Anggota_model.php
Line: 8
Function: generateID

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\perpustakaan\application\controllers\Anggota.php
Line: 78
Function: insert

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\perpustakaan\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Here it's my code:

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Anggota_model extends CI_Model {

    public function insert($id_petugas, $foto){
        $data = array(
            'ID_ANGGOTA'    => $this->generateID(),
            'ID_ADMIN'      => $id_petugas,
            'FULL_NAME'     => $this->input->post('nama_lengkap'),
            'TMP_LAHIR'     => $this->input->post('tmp_lahir'),
            'TGL_LAHIR'     => $this->input->post('tgl_lahir'),
            'ALAMAT'        => $this->input->post('alamat'),
            'GENDER'        => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'TELP'          => $this->input->post('telp'),
            'FOTO'          => $foto['file_name'],
            'D_CREATED'     => date('Ymd')
             );

        $this->db->insert('anggota', $data);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update($id){
        $data = array(
            'FULL_NAME'         => $this->input->post('nama_lengkap'),
            'ALAMAT'        => $this->input->post('alamat'),
            'TELP'      => $this->input->post('telp')
        );

        $this->db->where('ID_ANGGOTA', $id)->update('anggota', $data);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function generateID(){
        $query = $this->db->order_by('ID_ANGGOTA', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get('anggota')->row('ID_ANGGOTA');
        $lastNo = substr($query, 3);
        $next = $lastNo + 1;
        $kd = 'AGT';
        return $kd.sprintf('%03s', $next);
    }

    public function getList(){
        return $query = $this->db->order_by('id_anggota','ASC')->get('anggota')->result();
    }

    public function getCount(){
        return $this->db->count_all('anggota');
    }

    public function getDetail($id){
        return $this->db->where('ID_ANGGOTA', $id)->get('anggota')->row();
    }

    public function checkAvailability($id){
        $query = $this->db->where('ID_ANGGOTA', $id)->get('anggota');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $this->db->where('ID_ANGGOTA', $id)->delete('anggota');
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code you have is trying to extract a numeric value. It assumes the field being queried has the format `FOO123` or similar.

```php
$query = $this->db->order_by('ID_ANGGOTA', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get('anggota')->row('ID_ANGGOTA');
$lastNo = substr($query, 3);
```

However, the field you selected here doesn't contain what you think it does. It's actually a non-numerical string. Then, on the next line, you try to add one to it:

```php
$next = $lastNo + 1;
```

But that doesn't work if `$lastNo` is not numerical. For example:

```php
$query = query(...); // $query = 'FOOBAR';
$lastNo = substr($query, 3); // $lastNo = 'BAR';
$next = $lastNo + 1; // 'BAR' + 1 doesn't make any sense.
```

You'll need to inspect your database to see what value is actually in that field. You might just `var_dump()` it:

```php
$query = $this->db->order_by('ID_ANGGOTA', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get('anggota')->row('ID_ANGGOTA');
var_dump($query);
```

You might use a regex to only pick out the fields that match:

```php
$query = $this->db->(<whatever>);
if (preg_match('/^...(\d+)$/', $query, $match)) {
    $lastNo = $match[1];
} else {
    throw new Exception('Field did not match expected pattern');
}
```

Comment: FWIW in older PHP versions this was still a bad idea, but generated non-fatal warnings [PHP7] or just silently did the bad thing. [PHP<=5] https://3v4l.org/f49Yf